# Conflict between MathTime Pro 2, refcheck and braces in text mode

Tags: incompatibility, mtpro, refcheck

The following MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  a & \leq b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

And I get a `! Missing $ inserted.`. The problem disappears when `refcheck` is not used, or when `mtpro2` is not used.

Does anyone sees a way to use both packages simultaneously?

Also an input such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
Braces \{in text\}
\end{document}
```

produces the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mtpro2` redefines `\{` and `\}` in an incompatible way with respect to the usual LaTeX setting. It seems that restoring the commands to the right definition (after loading `mtpro2`) fixes the issue.

The problem might present itself also without `refcheck`, because the redefinition performed by `mtpro2` doesn't allow `\{` and `\}` to be used in text mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

\DeclareRobustCommand\{{\ifmmode\lbrace\else\textbraceleft\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand\}{\ifmmode\rbrace\else\textbraceright\fi}

\begin{document}
Braces \{in text\}

\begin{align}
  a & \leq b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Do I lose any functionality of `mtpro2` when redefining the braces as you suggested?

Comment: @mafp I don't think so. It's just an oversight by the package author.