# Curly braces in text mode using MathTime Pro don't work

Tags: pdftex, math-fonts

I'm trying to insert a curly brace in text mode, and typically I'd do this `\{ \}`:

However once I include the MathTime Pro font it refuses to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
    \{test\}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

```
Missing $ inserted. \{
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It seems the same problem as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87419/conflict-between-mathtime-pro-2-and-refcheck

Comment: Since the problem in the linked question is the same, I have made the question more general so as to encompass also yours. So we can close this one as duplicate: I hope you don't mind, it's just for avoiding scattering information around. It doesn't mean at all that your question is bad: to the contrary it is quite good.

Comment: @egreg Yes of course, no problem. Thanks for the solution!